# Storing arbitrary precision integers

Tags: python, arbitrary-precision

I am writing a little arbitrary precision in c(I know such libraries exist, such as gmp, nut I find it more fun to write it, just to exercise myself), and I would like to know if arrays are the best way to represent very long integers, or if there is a better solution(maybe linked chains)? And secondly how does python work to have big integers?(does it use arrays or another technique ?)

Thanks in advance for any response

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are asking about Python, C or a library written in C that will service Python?

Comment: Excuse me for my unclear question: I would like to write a library in c. But if I'm not wrong, python is written in c, so I would like to know how it works, to be able to perform such operations.

Comment: Do you plan to create mutable or immutable integers? If you want to support mutable integers, then *maybe* using linked-lists you could avoid some reallocation, but I doubt that it would be faster in the end.

Comment: Well, it depends, in functions, I would prefer mutable integers, since I would prefer passing the two operands(immutable) as `const` supposing it would be faster

Comment: I just had another question: Is it possible to have a an integer type with unlimited amount of bytes? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading documentation about `libgmp`, it already implements bigints. From what I see, it seems like integers are implemented as a dynamically allocated which is realloc'd when the number needs to grow. See http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Internals.html#Integer-Internals.

Comment: So if I understand well, gmp also stocks arbitrary integers in arrays? If I also understand well, it is an array if type `int`. And my question is, why not `short int` since each limbs only accept values between 0 and 9, if again, I understand well ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually it is efficient to use cells whose size is equal to a machine word, this is usually either `int` or `long`. Also, the number ar enot stored in base 10, but in a base N where N is the maximal value a cell can have. 

Example: let us say we are storing the number 770 and the cells are bytes, it would be stored as `2,3`, because `2 + 256*3 = 770`

Comment: So, in your example, each sell has N=255 ? Also, are you suggesting it would be faster and more economic to have a bigger base than 10 for each cell? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Python long integers are implemented as a simple structure with just an object header and an array of integers (which might be either 16- or 32-bit ints, depending on platform).

Code is at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f8942b8e6774/Include/longintrepr.h

Comment: Thank you for your quick and precise answer, but, due to the complexity of the code, where is ob_size defined?

Comment: object.h, same directory.

Comment: Thank you again, so if I understand well, long integers are mostly stored in `ob_digit` array?                                          
Thank you again